# Webdav on winxp cannot create network locations to multiple accounts on same server?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, webdav, network-drive

I'm trying to have a few 4shared accounts working with the windows webdav integration. However, when i give different login credentials in the map network drive wizard, and then open the second webdav folder I get to see the files from the first webdav folder.

It looks like windows doesn't make a different connection to the server to log in with different credentials.

Even after deleting the first folder I still only can access those files.

I have not tried rebooting yet.

Any clues?

update: with bitkinex it does work, but it is a bit silly to have to install extra software just for this. For all else explorer worked just fine.

Comment: As far as I know you cannot connect to a server with more than one set of credentials.

Comment: yeah, well, that is a bit shortsighted, innit?